# Why does my While loop Exit?

Tags: python, while-loop

My comments illustrate my line of reasoning but clearly I've got something wrong. My code just jumps straight to "Your total debt is..."

```
# Dictionary of Bills

expenses = {'mortgage':[], 'personal':[], 'power':[], 'insurance':[], 'water':[], 'food':[], 'savings':[], 'fuel':[], 'phone':[], 'internet':[], 'credit':[], 'emergencies':[]}
totalDebt = 0
switch = "A"

while switch == switch.isalpha(): # Condition is true, switch is a letter  
for each in expenses: # Iterates through each bill  
    debt = input("%s: "%each) # User input   
    if debt.isdigit(): # checks to make sure they only enter numbers  
        debt = int(debt) # Converts debt to its integer value  
        totalDebt = totalDebt + debt # adds debt to keep a running total.  


    else: # User entered something other than a number  
        print("Only enter digits!")  





print("Your total Debt is: $%i" %totalDebt)

input("Press Enter to continue: ")

print("What is this fortnights Income?")
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your condition doesn't make any sense here:

```
while switch == switch.isalpha(): # Condition is true, switch is a letter
```

`switch.isalpha()` returns either `True` or `False`. `switch` itself will not be equal to either of those two values, so the whole expression is always going to be `False`. Remove the equality test:

```
while switch.isalpha():  # Condition is true, switch is a letter
```

Note that your code never actually changes `switch`, so now your loop is going to continue forever.

Comment: It's so obvious now! I knew switch won't change (yet) it was driving me up the wall that it wouldn't work so I hadn't added the change switch clause.

Comment: Why does ending the while loop end the for loop that it is nested within?for each in expenses: # Itterates through each bill
    while switch.isalpha(): # Condition is true, switch is a letter
        debt = input("%s: "%each) # User input 
        if debt.isdigit(): # checks to make sure they only enter numbers
            debt = int(debt) # Converts debt to its integer value
            totalDebt = totalDebt + debt # adds debt to keep a running total.
            switch = "0" # Condition is False, switch is a number

Comment: @Boogz: You need to set `switch` back to a letter in the *next iteration*. `switch` doesn't magically change bak to `'A'` when `for` loops to the next expense.

Comment: @Boogz: in this context, you probably want to read [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658)

Answer (score 0):

The While is False

```
>>> switch
'A'
>>> switch.isalpha()
True
>>> switch == switch.isalpha()
False
```

You must use switch.isalpha() allown